What would be the physical characteristics of a human body after spending years in a liquid stasis tank with no sunlight or physical exercise?
Backstory
Subjects of a large project to breed specialized soldiers who will be used to fight and kill members of a story-specific group known for being super powered. They are bred in a lab from the genes of a female member of the super-powered group and from the day they are born they are kept in liquid stasis tanks — their subconscious minds are transferred to artificial organic bodies (similar to the movie Avatar).
Technical Information
While in the tank the subjects' bodies are well cared for. They are entirely submerged with various tubes and electrical probes for feeding and monitoring the bodies.
The tanks are designed is to keep the subjects sustained for long periods of time, possibly years. They are designed to filter out dead skin and provide artificial muscle stimulation to avoid atrophy. The liquid in the tank is oxygenated and the body breathes the liquid as babies do in the womb. The tanks are only designed to hold subjects until maturity.
Question Conditions
Story-based complications, however, have put the tanks in jeopardy. Consequently, the tanks are operating in a low-maintenance mode. The muscle stimulation has not operated for years, nor has any light. The brain has been engaged operating the artificial body for all this time.
In the story, one of these subjects (aged approximately 7 or 8) is discovered and introduced to his mother. This character has been in the tank in these conditions for 6-7 years. It is for this purpose that I need help determining a worldbuilding consequence.
Question: What would be the physical characteristics of a human body after spending years in a liquid stasis tank with no sunlight or physical exercise?

Babies in utero do not breathe the fluid they're immersed in. They are supplied with oxygen and get rid of carbon dioxide via their bloodstream, their umbilical cord and their placenta. You need to revise the life-support arrangements for the question to make sense.

@JohnDallman hm I had no idea that actually explains a lot. Ok yeah I will then have to rethink the example but yeah basically it's a special liquid oxygen so the child can at least breathe

Is this thought to be in a space ship? Or on a planet with gravity?

@Antares its on earth the tank just suspends him as if he is in space though like astronaut training

There are two solutions that I can see:

Perfectly healthy: if the creators of the stasis chambers can build a working stasis chamber, then they can probably also build nanomachines (or discover a new quantum field or develop interesting new medication or use a powerful benevolent bacteria) that preserves the body perfectly.
Sort of like being on a dark space station after not upkeeping yourself: This sounds sort of like being on a space station, barring the sunlight part. Without constant exercise, muscles will degrade after misuse - including the heart, if the body is suspended in a near-weightless state (like orbit, or in liquid). Without using the muscles, they degrade leading to the inability to properly beat one's heart without assistance due to the heart muscles falling into disuse. It might not be that bad, depending on conditions, but when the person needs to use their body for the first time in years, they will probably struggle to stand or manipulate objects with severely degraded leg, arm, and core muscles. This is a serious issue for astronauts, who must exercise many hours a day to keep their hearts working; if they don't, it will be too weak when they come back to Earth and they will be unable to pump blood into their brains and they will die.

One of these options is precluded by the specific statement that the tanks are operating in "low-maintenance" mode, which as with most modern tech turns off all the special extra features (see "battery saver" mode - makes your phone last longer, but often makes it work much worse and much slower). It still depends on what the creators defined as mission-critical to the tanks. Is it critical just that the person survive, or that they still retain enough functional muscle mass to walk around and pick stuff up as normal one they wake up?
You further specify that muscle stimulation has not been online in years. In that case, of course the muscles will degrade. What I would consider then is what point the tanks were meant to serve: if the user wakes up without any functional muscles, why get in in the first place? Wouldn't it be at least a faster and less painful death by whatever the jeopardy outside is than to keep the stasisee alive until they wake up and subsequently starve when they can't even stand up from their tank? (Of course it's your story, so you do you with that, but an interesting consideration.)

Yeah truth be told it's only one person but when I made this question in the sandbox someone edited it to be a group and told me that having it be a group instead of one character would decrease likelihood of my question being flagged, as for the story itself the creators basically decided that they only really need his brain and in the story his mother can switch from avatar body to her real body instantly through special teleporting tech and will sometimes use this method in a fight, so the people behind the project hadn't quite decided if they wanted to let him keep his body and..

(Continued) start conditioning it to peak human levels or just cut out his brain and rely on the avatar being able to take on his mom outside her avatar body (odds are they would've  chosen the latter) and since it would've been difficult to just cut out the brain of a newborn without causing serious damage to the brain, so the tank was really there to hold the subject until he reached the physical age where they can just remove his brain with minimal issues if they decide to go that route and the scientists involve evacuating is less for the subject's survival and more for there own survival

(Continue) as well as protecting their research and protecting what one would call an "asset"  until they can breed a better one that makes the subject in question obsolete seeing these subjects less as people and more of expendable tools

They will be functionally blind and deaf for months, and will flail around like a toddler for even longer.
Your brain can't learn to see and hear completely using diffrent sets of sense organs, It needs to learn all the quirks of your particular organs. We know from transplants that they will spend months severly impaired as their brain learns to interpret the "new" organs, thankfully the magic virtual simulation should allow for most normal developmental critical periods so they can still speak and see and hear eventually, but there are some thing just will not work.
Critical periods are time dependent things your brain has to learn by a certain time othewise the pathways break down. For instance if you don't learn a language by around age 5-7 you will never be able to learn a fully developed language, that is with fully developed sintax, you will never be fluent in ANY language. The parts of the brain that need to do it just don't form the right connections, and most inportantly cannot gain them later one. Do it by age X or it does not happen.
Your issue is basically all strong critical periods are past by age 7, so the virtual training is everything. But some critical periods rely on using your sense organs with complex feedbacks.
Two strong critical period that truly rely on the real organs will be depth perception and  musical pitch, these are gone for the person, they will never have more than crude approximations even with extensive training. Depth perception relies on precise interpretation of a very narrow margin of overlap the singnals in your real visual feilds during very early childhood. there is a very precise feedback with signal, eye movment, and the actualy overlapping neuron pattern in your brain. Even people with eye misalignment often fail to develop it. Thankfully depth perception is a minor inconvinece, and as someone without it, also has an upside since you learn to think in 3D because you don't see in 3D. So don't expect them to be able to play catch well or be any good with a sword. Basically any tasks that is realy hard to do with ony one eye.
Voice pitch relies on hearing how your voice soinds and comparing it to the other sounds, it is intirely dependant on using your real voice in a feedback loop, you can't learn it properly othrwise. Your people will not be good singers and they may well have a unique accent their entire life. They will never have good pitch for instance because they did not learn to interpret and make sound using the real organs. This will likyl cause severe distortion in their voice as well as they have never actually used their real muscles and voicebox and all the unique quirks it has.
Movment is going to be a mess for them as well expect years of physical therapy to even be able to do normal moveoment with any precision, all the msucles responses are "wrong" as far as their brain is concerned. Thankfully with virtual feedback they should still be able to move and speak eventually because the brain learned the basics. So they just take a long time to learn their "new" muscles. Considering how atrophies said muscles will be this may take decades. But also consider this is everything at once not just one organ so they can't communicate in either dirrection for a while so it may take a lot longer.
How long the artifical muscle stimulation has been down will matter a lot
Some bone and muscle do not develop properly without use, so it should be working to al least age 5, otherwise they may suffer a lot of malformations in muscle and relatd tissue like lungs and joints. This is triply so with the lack of effective gravity on bone.
You need magic space technology for them to have properly developed bones
Since their bones have never experienced proper loading. Without such handwavium they will not even be able to stand upright, ever. Many bones have to loaded to grow in the right shape and muscle stimultion alone can't do that. So many important bones will be malformed without it. This is not simple bone loss, the bones will not even be shaped or connected to ever function properly.
You may be better off saying the artifical stimulation and hadwavium tech only stopped recently otherwise your people will spend decades on physical therapy just for normal function. Consider treating it more like being bed ridden for a few years.
More on critical periods.

Ok wow that is interesting. Yeah it's only really one person who has to go through this in the story but I was told to make it a group since asking questions about individual characters tends to result in flagging and I knew in terms of appearance he'd likely look like a sick pickled lizard child and probably wouldn't be able to move that well for a while but I didn't even think about any of that. Also in the story they do have nanoscopic technology and medical knowledge so they could easily fix the muscle atrophy and I'll likely put it where the skeleton is harder to deal with. You have given

(Continue) me some ideas since I may add that depth perception and vocal issues detail.

(Wouldn't let me edit previous comment) in fact that coupled with him never actually being in any real social setting or being social etiquette means that he'll especially gave a hard time adjusting to society in ways that make for possible story telling that didn't even occur to me, thank you this was very helpful

@Melchizadek you could easily ask several questions about their virtual upbringing, like what has to be simulated, like he has to hve language interaction, emotional cueing, emotion control feedback (you can't throw an temper tanturum) ect. And yeah most people don't realize atrophy is only half the equation, your entire nervous system is analog and has to be programed by use because everyones sytem is very diffrent on the details. look at upside down goggles for just a taste of how disorienting learning a change in your senses are.

Man I only asked question to figure out what the poor child look like but now I'm getting way more information that I'm enjoying right now and yeah as someone who has high functioning autism (as I was told aspergers is no longer a used term) I definitely know that everyone systems are different

Probably weakened but also recoverable (quickly).
I am assuming the world is a planet, with gravity. But also in a zero-G environment on a spaceship or station this might be true up to a degree. Problematic in zero-G is the missing gravity to enhance muscle buildup of course.
Real world example you can refer to are long term coma patients. Or astronauts (especially shortly after they have returned to earth again).
Concerns:
(A) Muscular Condition:
Sure muscles might be atrophied, lung capacity is low, blood pressure not optimal, heart rate high, bone structure weakened, etc.
But also a human body (and a super powered one surely as well) is also able to adapt to changing environment conditions fairly quickly.
At the beginning the body might not be able to stand, nor be able to grab hold to something, wearing armor, carrying or using a weapon, maybe even need help feeding himself, learning to "really" speak (using the mouth and the lungs, not some virtual reality analogue), etc.
But after a while, the muscles will build up. All symptoms of degeneration will vanish over time. How long that takes? Maybe like a physical rehab after a severe accident. Something between 3 months and 3 years maybe.
(B) No sunlight:
Humans are not that dependent on sunlight. We do not do photosynthesis, you know ;) It might take a while to adapt the eyes to bright light, causing headache, nausea, etc. Sun glasses might help alleviate most of that. At some point the eyes will adapt to the bright light.
(C) No body functions:
A little more of a concern might be that almost all body functions were never in use even once. Digestive system, lungs, temperature control (sweating, shivering), dexterity of fingers, using the mouth to talk, hairs and nails being long (curled and uncut), etc. It seems that the brain is the only stimulated organ of that body.
Training especially the digestive system might be problematic. The newborn phase is needed to build up a "flora", a set of bacteria that help digesting food and recover the nutritions from them.
Conclusion:
I would argue that a person wakes up severely hampered but the conditions are temporary if there is enough medical support present that allows or supports recovering and adapting to the "real world" environment outside the tank.

Oh yeah no I'm putting it where the group who finds him have technology to fix these problem semi easily with the exception of having to get used to his real body, I'm mainly just looking at what he would like after that period of time as well possible ailments and health issues to be dealt with, and yeah I barely saw your comment from earlier yeah he's on earth but suspended in a giant liquid tank so kind of like long terms astronaut training underwater but with no real treatment for years

My read?
Dissolved.
Even in the womb, an environment intended by eons of natural selection to be as hospitable as possible, human babies only make it the 9 months they have to be in there because we've adapted vernix, a cheesy, greasy coating for baby's skin in utero, which is excreted by fetal skin in the last few months of gestation and usually washed off shortly after birth. Most other mammals have adapted the same coating, even marine mammals adapted to live in seawater far more salty than the roughly isotonic amniotic fluid of the womb.
Try putting a human back into a liquid environment, and within days, their outer skin layers will be falling apart, sloughing off in the body's desperate attempt to rid itself of this breeding ground for gangrene, but in the process exposing the vulnerable inner layers of the skin, including raw nerves and delicate elastic tissue of the dermis. Once this process starts, without prompt, intensive medical care, gangrene is exactly what you'll get, and you'll be lucky to only lose limbs.
We call this condition "trench foot", as it's common among soldiers (and other outdoorsmen) who fail to dry out their feet between rainstorms while trudging through churned-up muck wearing mostly-waterproof boots. Only in this case with the person's skin submerged in a tank, it won't just be the soles of the feet, it'll be every inch of the person's skin. You can match the water in the tank to body chemistry (pH, electrolyte content), that'll actually just make the deterioration happen quicker as this liquid plays havoc with the body's expectation of external vs internal homeostatic environment. An artificial protective coating, like petroleum jelly, will only work for so long even if regularly touched up and reapplied, and if the advanced maintenance systems in the tank have reverted to core life support I wouldn't bet the robotic reapplication apparatus is still functioning.
Long story short, humans aren't built to live in tanks. Our skin is designed to breathe in open air. Even if you design what you'd imagine as the ideal liquid environment to be in long-term contact with our skin, you're working against hundreds of millenia of evolution of our own species and millions of years more of evolution of our terrestrial ancestors.

Oh wow that sounds pretty bad, yeah I'll have to take that into consideration. I mean these guys have advanced tech such as nanoscopic machines that regrow entire limbs so these issues will definitely be temporary but still. I may add the addition of some wonder gel design to last long and protect the skin as well some device to keep the internal homeostasis in check. Then again as mentioned these guys have advanced tech to fix these issues, putting preventative feels kind of moot
